# Overriding the value of const

Tags: reactjs, constants

So I was reading an [article](https://css-tricks.com/an-overview-of-render-props-in-react/) and stumbled and saw this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kinsomicrote/pen/pxyvwX) and saw that in `increment` method it is setting `count` as `const` and I'm quite unable to process this, that How can you override `const`? Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

```js
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  // Increase count
  increment = () => {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return this.setState({ count: count + 1 });
  };
```

Why declare `const` when you can use `let` or `var` because usage of `const` is quite confusing knowing the deconstructed variable is going to be manipulated?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. The code in the question doesn't have `const` anywhere and it doesn't "override" anything.

Comment: @JJJ it seems like someone edited it. and what part are you unclear about the question?

Comment: 1) What `const` are you talking about (there is no `const` in the code) and 2) what part do you think is "overriding" something?

Comment: @JJJ it should be clear now edited the question and you can also see the codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not overriding the behavior of `const`. The increment is happening, not by changing the value of the `const count` variable, but by calling `setState` which will replace (asynchronously) the entire state of the component. Then the next time increment or decrement is called, `count` will receive the new value via the deconstructing assignment from `this.state` -- that isn't a change to the variable's value, it is a new variable (local to the increment function) each time `increment` is called.

Comment: Point taken, but why use `const`, doesn't it a bit of bad practice given that you know you have to change the state?

Comment: @YashKaranke Yup, horrible example of using `const`. There are entire camps of people who believe "use const for everything unless the variable *has* to be reassigned", which leads to ambiguity and also does not tell the reader what is actually important to not be reassigned vs. what just happens to not be reassigned, but won't hurt anything if it is. It dilutes the meaning of `const`, kinda like the story of the boy who cried wolf. lol

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reassign `const`. There's a reason it's named as `const`, short form for `constant`. It means, once you define it, it cannot be reassigned.

Variable that has to and needs to be reassigned should be declared as `let`.

```
let a = 'a';
a = 'new value'; // this is allowed

const x = 'x';
x = 'new value'; // this is not allowed
```

`var` will also let you reassign a value, but it's an old notation and you'll mostly won't need to use var unless for rare specific cases.

In the code from the question

```
const { count } = this.state;
```

the count value is destructured from state and assigned to a variable named `count`, meaning it is a copy of the value `this.state.count` and not `this.state.count` itself.

Comment: I agree with you, but when you see the given codepen link in the question, it is `const`

Comment: @YashKaranke I just went through the codepen link. `count` is not overridden anywhere. This line `this.setState({ count: count + 1 })` only means setting the key `count` from the state and not the `count` that was destructured in the above line.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but "overridden" is an ambiguous term. The *value* absolutely can be overridden. `const` means the variable cannot be *reassigned*

Comment: @mhodges You're right. I'll edit the answer for clarity.

Comment: While this answer is factually correct, I'm not sure that it answers the OP's question. I think they are asking why, if they declare `count` as a `const` (via deconstruction), can that count property on the state object be overwritten. The answer would be that the `count` variable is a copy of the *value*, not a reference to the property itself. So declaring it `const` is only declaring it for that variable, the object property is untouched.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `const { count } = this.state;`, you are actually creating a **copy** of `this.state.count`, not manipulating `this.state.count` directly.

And `const` is there as not to accidentally manipulate it unless you need to.

Following code snippet demos that updating "copy" of `count` doesn't update the `state.count`

(click on `Run Code Snippet` to see the result).

```js
const state = { count: 0 };
let {count} = state;
count += 999;

console.log(`state.count`, state.count);
console.log(`count`, count);
```

And this will fail (miserably).

```js
const state = { count: 0 };
const {count} = state;
count += 999;

console.log(`state.count`, state.count);
console.log(`count`, count);
```

Comment: @YashKaranke no you can't, if you had declared it as `const`. I used `let` to make it modifiable for demo purpose only.  If you had `const {count} = state;` and do `count += 999`, the snippet will fail. (updated the answer)

Answer (score -1):

You can't override const another meaning is you can't reassign const.

```
const a = 1;
a = 2; // you will get TypeError.  *** numbers and strings are also immutable
```

but you can modify the constant without reassigning the type

```
const b = {};
b.a = 'new property'; // { a: "new property" }

const c = [];
c[0] = "new stack"; // ["new stack"]
```

You can modify but you can't reassign const.